# how to bit shift the variable and form the whole value

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have the following code in C:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t result;
uint8_t bit[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

since each element of `bit` array takes 8 bits, and variable `result` take 32 bits, I want to form the `result` using 4 elements in the `bit` array, `bit[0]` takes the most significant bit(MSB) 8 bits of `result`, `bit[1]` takes the second MSB 8 bits of `result`,  `bit[2]` takes the third MSB 8 bits of `result`,  `bit[3]` takes the least significant bit 8 bits of `result`, how to form it in C?

I know the bit shift operator, but after shift all the elements, how to combine them together to form a value?

Comment: Help for what? read [ask].

Comment: Are you familiar with the bit shift operator `<<`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh ok, I will

Comment: 1) it's unclear what you mean by "first". Use "lowest/highest address" or "least/most significant" instead. 2)Do you want a solution that works for both big and small endian machine or a fast solution that only works for either?

Comment: I just want to have some tips how to form it, or if you have a solution I can learn, it is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic approach is to shift the values accordingly and bitwise OR them:

```
result = bit[3] | (bit[2] << 8) | (bit[1] << 16) | (bit[0] << 24);
```

When you perform a shift operation on a type that is smaller than an `int`, it will automatically be "promoted" to an `int` (look up "integer promotion"). Since `int` is is at least 32 bits on all real systems, this code is safe in a practical sense.

But, if you need to work with a data type larger than an int, you should cast the `bit[x]` to the target type before shifting. If, for example you are working on a platform where int is 16 bits (e.g. 8086), the correct code would be:

```
result = (uint32_t)bit[3] | ((uint32_t)bit[2] << 8) | ((uint32_t)bit[1] << 16) | ((uint32_t)bit[0] << 24);
```

(this has some needless casting, but illustrates a point and doesn't harm anything)

Similarly, if `result` was `uint64_t` and you had 8 elements in `bit`, you'd need to cast them all to `uin64_t`, as by default they will only get promoted to `int`, which is (likely) 32bit.

---

However, if you want to access specific bytes of a `uint32_t` you can declare them as a union:

```
union { uint32_t result; uint8_t bytes[4]; } u;
u.result = 0xabcdef12;
u.bytes[2] = 0x78;
printf("%x", u.result);
```

Comment: @Minato Not really. This is one of the few cases (in c11) where type punning through an union is without dangers, only because uint32_t can't have a trap representation (as far as I know).

Comment: @this well I used them in my Artificial Intelligence programs.. and found them to be insanely fast and memory efficient... when I need to combine 4 chars to make up at int or even at bit level memory optimizations... :).. but memory management is a pain

Comment: @Minato Unions are not elegant because they are endianess-dependent. If the first example, you can _know_ that array of index 0 contains the least significant byte, no matter system. In the union example, the contents of index 0 depend on endianess.

Comment: but if the bit[3] is a uint_8, can it be shifted to the bits more than uint_8?

Comment: @ratzip It can, it is promoted to int. Depending on your system/compiler you may need to cast it if shifting by more than 31 (bits in int), but in this case you are safe.

Comment: @user3528438 It doesn't. Look up "anonymous unions" - basically you can declare two variables that share the same memory location, without wrapping them in a named union (e.g. no need for `u.result` and `u.bytes`)

Comment: @mtijanic, sorry to ask, but what you mean by casting it, can you update you solution there?

Comment: @mtijanic user352... was saying that your code is wrong, and it is.

Comment: @this You are correct, sorry, changed. The code worked in C++ and gnu11, but not c11.

Comment: @ratzip Added an explanation and example